# CSS file in same view/scripts folder as phtml file

Tags: zend-framework

I have a CSS file that is in the same view/scripts folder as the `phtml` file that will use it. What is the correct parameter for `$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet()` for such a file?

Answer (score 1):

Your css file must be accessible in public directory or public subdirectory like `public/css/your_css_file.css`

In your view, you can do something like this:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl() .'/css/your_css_file.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally your CSS file should be accessible publicly (within the public folder).

However, if you still want to leave it there (you will have performance issues especially if your file is large) just do so within your view file

```
<?php

$this->headStyle()->captureStart();
echo $this->partial('css-file.css');
$this->headStyle()->captureEnd();

?>
```

This will allow your file contents to be output, captured and then "injected" in the appropriate place in the layout.

Hope it helps